# mail sending fails in shell

Tags: email, shell, mutt

I get an error attempting to send mail with the following command.

```
mutt -s "testing message" -a 123.jpeg file.txt abc123@gmail.com < file.txt
```

error message is coming on the screen.

> 553 delivery from 122.161.253.17 is rejected.

But i know that my ip is 10.127.0.1 which is type of internal ip. Can you please help to solve this problem.

Comment: That's probably to do with the SMTP server rejecting emails from your host. This is not a programming issue. Perhaps try [sf]?